# Paraboloid volume

Tags: analysis

i need some help to calculate the volume of a paraboloid.
The only things i have given is

$R \in (0,\infty]$ and $P_{R}:= \bigl\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}:0≤z≤1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{R^2}\bigr\}$

I tried to calculate the volume with this one

$$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \int _{-\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}} \int \limits_{0}^1 1\, dz\, dy\, dx$$

but i didn't got something plausible.
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is not correct. If you want to use cartesian coordinates, try this one
$$V=\int \limits_{0}^1\left(\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2(1-z)}1 dxdy\right)dz.$$
Note that the internal integral is the area of the planar set $\{x^2+y^2\leq R^2(1-z)\}$ which is a disc centered at the origin with radius $R\sqrt{1-z}$. Hence
$$V=\pi R^2\int_{0}^1(1-z)\, dz.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: hey thanks for answer,

i don't understand how exactly you got the bound of $x^2+y^2 ≤ R^2(1-z)$ and also how to calculate the integral with this bound.

Comment: It follows from the inequality $z\leq 1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{R^2}$. Ther is no need to calculate this integral because $\int_A 1dxdy$ is the area of $A$. In thiis case $A$ is a disc or radius $R\sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: ah ok now i got it, thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 2):

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^R r\left(1-\dfrac{r^2}{R^2}\right)drd\theta$

Comment: thank you for answer but i want to calculate it without using polar coordinates